# How can I use Texmaster on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: games, 19.10

fellow Ubuntu users ! Recently, I've been wanting to play Texmaster again, but I don't have a clue about using it on Ubuntu 19.10. It used to work on Ubuntu 10.04 I believe, and when you search for Texmaster, you find a bunch of files, and two and two .gz
[Here is what I can find in the folder downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDX74.png)
I don't know if I can use it with what I got, or if I have to find something else. Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually found a solution : I can use the .exe with Wine. It actually works like it should, so my problem is quite solved

Comment: Excellent! Please click on the checkmark to the left of your answer to show others it worked so they will know what to do to run it themselves. Also, adding it to the Wine apps database at https://appdb.winehq.org/ would also help others, as I did not find it there when I checked.

Answer (score 1):

The folks who have the source code aren't getting it into the Ubuntu repositories any more, and haven't since [2012 as per their web page](https://repology.org/project/texmaster/versions). No alternative is listed at https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=texmaster but since Texmaster itself is a Tetris clone, I searched further and found [these Tetris-like games](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=tetris&ignoreExactMatch=true&platform=linux) which are available.

The [game's author](https://tetrisconcept.net/members/report.46/) can also be contacted.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the folder you downloaded is missing a few files.

Make a copy of Texmaster2009.ini and rename it Texmaster2009.ubuntu10.04.ini

Make a copy of Texmaster2009.nv and rename it Texmaster2009.ubuntu10.04.nv

Make a copy of Texmaster2009.sav and rename it Texmaster2009.ubuntu10.04.sav

(Yes.. I know they’re missing the .amd64 [and/or .i386] bit from the ends.. I assume this is so the same files will work with both the 32 and 64 bit versions.)

Then see if you can launch Texmaster2009.ubuntu10.04.amd64 from a terminal.

Hope this helps.